# How to cover with typescript sequelize findAll with include

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to type static class method of sequelize model which return findAll with include:

```
import { Model, Optional } from 'sequelize';
import Rule from './rule';

interface OfferAttributes {
  id: number;

  name: string;
}
type OfferCreationAttributes = Optional<OfferAttributes, 'id'>;

export class Offer extends Model<OfferAttributes, OfferCreationAttributes> implements OfferAttributes {
  public readonly id!: number;

  public name!: string;

  public static getWithRules() {
    // error here
    return Offer.findAll<Offer & { rules: Rule[] }>({ include: ['rules']});
  }
}
```

I prefer to use generic instead of unknow solution like this:

```
Offer.findAll({ include: ['rules']}) as unknown as Promise<(Offer & { rules: Rules[] })[]>
```

but get error `Property 'rules' is missing in type 'Offer' but required in type '{ rules: Rule[]; }'.` Generic of findAll is `<M extends Model>` but it's not match `<Offer & { rules: Rules[] }>`

Does anybody know the most correct way to cover this case with generic?